# php clean extra parameters in urls

Tags: php

when I post a link to facebook such as this one `http://www.zzz.com/images.php?i=kwlhjv`
when the users on facebook clicks on the link they are directed to the same page I posted but with another parameters that facebook add to the url
How can I remove those get parameters with php ?
(I still want to keep my `i=kwlhjv` parameter)
example of facebook redirect url :

```
http://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zzz.com%2Fimages.php%3Fi%3Dkwlhjv%26ref%3Dnf&h=TAQGrLLtbAQEG_HgubmSe57WD1q-uf0_kz_-2ADc6jr9xAw&s=1
```

Comment: Do you experience any *real* issues with this?

Comment: yes, I am saving users visits to my database. I don't want the long urls.

Comment: also google analytic reads each url as individual page while all users are mostly on the same page.

Comment: Do you have a whitelist of allowed GET parameters? Or a list of Facebook's parameters?

Comment: the only parameters that I want is the i=kwlhjv

Comment: does it matter how many get variables are there in saving data into database

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $val) {
  if ($key != 'i') {
    unset($_GET[$key])
  }
}
```